# How to filter the http by using the top command?

Tags: top

I am running `siege`, then I run the command `top` to monitor the process.

```
siege -u http://adm/login -d1 -r10 -c1000

top
```

When I run top command whole system process will run, so I need to filter. Only know this http request response.
How to filter by using the top command ?

Answer (score 6):

It is possible that each distro version of `top` is different. You will need to check `man top`, but try the following.

To start `top` showing only process you started:

```
top -u <username>
```

Filter process (commands) while running `top`. For example, show only `firefox`:

- Start `top` as per normal
- Press <kbd>o</kbd>
- Enter `COMMAND=firefox` then <kbd>Enter</kbd>

There is heaps to `top`, read the manual :]

Comment: Helpfully the prompt uses `?`!
`add filter #3 (ignoring case) as: [!]FLD?VAL`

Answer (score -3):

you can filter your process generated by httpd using following command:

```
top | grep httpd
```

its working fine on my machine.